# Erro no autoload ao usar HighchartsPHP

Tags: php, composer, highcharts

Estou incluindo em meu composer **"ghunti/highcharts-php": "~3.0"** e após isso o meu autoload para de funcionar resultando no fatal error abaixo, o que poderia ser?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::setPsr4() in
>   /Users/my-user/my-project/dev/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
>   on line 37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se o seu composer e o arquivo `vendor/autoload.php` estão atualizados.

Antes de executar o `composer update`, execute os comandos abaixo:

Para atualizar o composer:

```
composer selfupdate
```

Para gerar novamente o `vendor/autoload.php`:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Ao final, certifique que esteja importando adequadamente os `namespaces` necessários através de `use`

Segue um exemplo de uma página funcionando com a instancia do `Highcharts`

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Ghunti\HighchartsPHP\Highchart;

$chart = new Highchart();

var_dump($chart);
```

Comment: Executei mas mesmo assim o problema ainda persiste.

Comment: Mesmo erro Daniel?

Comment: Sim, mesmo erro, me parece que é algo relacionado com o **psr-4**. Ele fala que a função não existe mas se abro o **ClassLoader** a função **setPsr4** está lá certinho.

Comment: @Daniel editei minha resposta, se não der certo edite sua pergunta e inclua seu `composer.json`. Fiz um projetinho novo usando essa biblioteca e está funcionando sem problemas.

Comment: Criei um projeto novo aqui e funcionou direitinho também, acredito que deve ser conflito com alguma outra biblioteca do meu projeto, vou tentar descobrir o que é agora. Obrigado.

Comment: Daniel, caso precise de ajuda poste seu `composer.json`

Comment: Achei o problema. Tenho um subprojeto com seu **composer.json** específico que estava sobrescrevendo o **composer.json** global.